# How to connect a fingerprint with a SQL database?

Tags: android, sql-server, fingerprint

I am currently working on a fingerprint application in Android. When I enter a fingerprint I want to link it to a SQL data and, when that person is logged in,  show their information from my SQL database.

How can I connect this fingerprint with a database?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to get fingerprint id from the sensor. So your idea of storing fingerprints in database won't work.

Your fingerprint is secure and it is not share with Google.

For further details check the Android documentation for fingerprint

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html